# indented div with flexible width

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a div that starts 200px from the left and extends to the edge of the page on the right but not beyond.  Right now with 100% as the width it extends 200px beyond the page to the right.  Without the width, it still extends beyond by 200px.

Any idea how to make this work?

```
#MsgBanner{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#333;
  top:60px;
  height:30px;
  z-index:14;
  width:100%;
  left:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
#MsgBanner {
width: auto;
margin-left: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it's not possible without the calc() function introduced in CSS3.

```
#MsgBanner{
   position:relative;
   background-color:#333;
   top:60px;
   height:30px;
   z-index:14;
   width:calc(100% - 200px);
   left:200px;
}
```

Above would solve the problem in CSS3, but it's not supported by all browsers.

Comment: Definitely works.  Hopefully everyone will support css 3 soon!

Answer (score 0):

```
#MsgBanner{  position:relative;  background-color:#333;  top:60px;  height:30px;  z-index:14;  width:100%;  margin-left:200px;}
```

I think all you need to do is set the margin on the left to 200px instead.

Comment: Width has to be auto.  This still extends beyond the screen.